# Select2 with Bootstrap3 not styling correctly

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-select2

I'm trying to use latest version of Select2 with the css styles of [t0m](https://github.com/t0m/select2-bootstrap-css/tree/bootstrap3)
However, the select form keeps its Select2 style and won't change.
Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">

<head>

<!-- stylesheets -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="select2/select2.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="select2/select2-bootstrap.css">
<style type="text/css">
body {
  padding: 40px;
}
</style>

<!-- scripts -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="select2/select2.js"></script>
<script src="select2/select2_locale_it.js"></script>

<script>
$(function(){
  // turn the element to select2 select style
  $('#select2').select2();
});
</script>
</head>

<body>

<select id="select2" class="input-default" style="width:300px">
  <optgroup label="Alaskan/Hawaiian Time Zone">
    <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
    <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Pacific Time Zone">
    <option value="CA">California</option>
    <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
    <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
    <option value="WA">Washington</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Mountain Time Zone">
    <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
    <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
    <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
    <option value="MT">Montana</option>
    <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
    <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
    <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
    <option value="UT">Utah</option>
    <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Central Time Zone">
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
    <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
    <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
    <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
    <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
    <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
    <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
    <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
    <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
    <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
    <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
    <option value="TX">Texas</option>
    <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
    <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Eastern Time Zone">
    <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
    <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
    <option value="FL">Florida</option>
    <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
    <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
    <option value="ME">Maine</option>
    <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
    <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
    <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
    <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
    <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
    <option value="NY">New York</option>
    <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
    <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
    <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
    <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
    <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
    <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
    <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
    <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
</body>

</html>
```

I tried everything I could, however nothing changed, except if I 
added the class `form-control` it happens [this](https://imageshack.com/i/kmFpqZbpp)

Comment: What is the problem here. .. http://jsfiddle.net/kheema/t5whj/5/

Comment: this https://imageshack.com/i/kmFpqZbpp

Comment: What seems to be the problem? I understand that if you add the `form-control` class, it will show a border and that's not your intention. Just dont add that class. This [jsfidle](http://jsfiddle.net/nr8L8gjk/) behaves like the [plugin demo](http://fk.github.io/select2-bootstrap-css/).